# automatic container size in column

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a calendar like overview.

There are multiple containers that should be added to this column. Each container has an offset relative to the top. But there's a chance multiple containers will overlap. So they should be next to each other. (see example image).

Each container has a specific height, but the width should be as large as possible.

[image: Ordering example]

What's the most efficient way to do this in Flutter?

Otherwise, manually calculating the width of each container and horizontal offset would be an option.

Comment: wrap the container with expanded widget and try

Comment: also stack and positioned are usable